# PHP mail function can't send to att.net, MAIL FROM line is incorrect

Tags: php, email, postfix

When web apps on my VPS use the PHP built-in `mail` function, some domains (like att.net) bounce emails back. `/var/log/mail.log` reveals:

```
550 [PERMFAIL] att.net requires valid sender domain (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Basically the `MAIL FROM` line is something like `<user@myhost>` when it should be `<user@myhost.com>`, so AT&T's mail server doesn't like it.

I'm not entirely sure if my `/etc/hostname` file needs to be myhost or myhost.com. Any time I try to change it to myhost.com, upon reboot it reverts back to myhost.

I'm at a loss here.

EDIT:

Apparently `/etc/hostname` (according to Google searches) should be just the hostname, not the FQDN. If I type `hostname --fqdn`, then I get the FQDN.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was a fast self-solution!

The `myorigin` line in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` was set to `/etc/hostname`. I commented out that line so it defaults to `$myhostname` which is set to my FQDN. All is well.